# Create .htaccess with a variable

Tags: .htaccess

I am having trouble finding a solution for what I want to do. I am going to have a couple thounsand affiliates signing up on our site. They will provide a username, and basically give out the url www.domain.com/affiliate/username to their clients.

So, the url I will be starting with is www.domain.com/affiliate/home.html?userid=bob (if bob is the username they give).

I need that to check with the mysql database if that userid exists, then redirect it to the www.domain.com/affiliate/bob url.

Right now, I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)$ affiliate/home.html?affiliate=$1 [L]
```

It obviously doesnt work and Ive never dealt with .htaccess before. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Where is your htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^affiliate/([^/]+)/?$ /affiliate/home.html?affiliate=$1 [L]
```

As for redirecting to the nicer looking URL if someone enters the one with the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /affiliate/home.html\?affiliate=([^\ &]+)&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /affiliate/%2?%3 [L,R=301]
```

There's no way to check if a username is in your database before the rewrite happens, using an htaccess file. There's ways to talk to a database in apache 2.4 or using a `RewriteMap` (which can only be defined in server or vhost config, not in htaccess) but you're better off doing the check in your home.html and just return a 404 if the user isn't found.

Comment: home.html should be home\.html because it is a regex in the second rule

Comment: Thanks guys. Jon Lin, your worked perfect. A second question if I may, is there a way to keep that affiliate/bob/ there in the url as long as they are on the site? So right now if there were to click a link on the site, it would deviate from affilate/bob. Is there a way to keep the affiliate name in the url?

Comment: @dkeeper09 You need to change the URLs within your own content to point to the right URLs

Comment: I understand what you mean..I think. So if I have another page, about.html or whatever, what would the url look like to keep the affiliate/username in the url?

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer on an other similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327693/how-to-redirect-site-com-forum-index-php-to-site-com-forum/17328067#17328067).

You want `www.domain.com/affiliate/home.html?userid=bob` to be redirected to `/affliate/bob`. You want `/affliate/bob` to be rewritten to `/affiliate/home.html?userid=bob`.

---

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your `/www/` or `/public_html/`.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^affiliate=([^&]*)$
RewriteRule ^affiliate/home\.html /affiliate/%1? [R,L]

RewriteRule ^affiliate/(.*)$ affiliate/home.html?affiliate=$1&r=0 [L]
```

The first rule matches if the user tries to access `affiliate/home.html?userid=bob`. The RewriteCondition matches the part of the query string (after the ?) that you need to write the fancy url. `%1` matches the first 'capturing group' in a rewrite condition. The `?` at the end will clear the query string. `[R]` means it is a redirect (see the linked answer what that does). `[L]` means it will stop matching if this one matches.

The second rule is an internal rewrite. `$1` matches the first 'capturing group' in the RewriteRule. The trailing `&r=0` is there to stop the first rule from matching. It requires a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` to function properly, because the fancy url is in the same directory is the file that handles it.

Comment: Ok, so I tried that code in my .htaccess. Put in my public_html folder. 
A few things wrong I think.
1. It doesn't rediritect if i put in affiliate/home.html?userid=bob
2. Then if I put in www.domain.com/affiliate/bob it redirects to www.domain.com/domain/affiliate/bob

Also, is there way to check the userid with the mysql database before the redirect happens? I want it to make sure that if someone puts in www.domain.com/affiliate/bob that its an actual affiliate in our database. Does that make sense?

Comment: You can't use .htaccess to perform that check. You have to do that check in home.html (or home.php probably) and redirect the user from the php file to an other page if the user doesn't exist in the database (something like `header( "Location: WhaargErrorPage.php" );` I think). `/domain/affiliate/bob` is probably caused by an other rewriterule, messing with the url before it gets to my part. I suppose it is located in `httpd.conf`.

Comment: If you can't move my rewriterules before the rewriterule that is messing with the redirect, put `RewriteRule ^yourdomain/(.*)$ $1` before all redirects and `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ yourdomain/$1` directly after all redirects (`[R]`). I think that should negate it for redirects, as that rewrite is solely for finding the correct file on the server.

Comment: Your rules produces a rewrite loop, since the rewrite engine will continue to loop through all your rules unless the URI stops changing. So after `/affiliate/bob` gets rewritten to `/affiliate/home.html?affiliate=bob`, the first rule gets applied and redirects the browser to the same URL, `/affiliate/bob`

Comment: @JonLin Did you test that? I thought the rewriterules were only applied if either the page was loaded, or if the page was redirected (in which case the browser requests the url you put in the redirect). The second rewriterule will do an internal rewrite, which is invisble to the browser.

Comment: Yes, I tested, did you test it? Firefox says "The page isn't redirecting properly" and the rewrite log tells me exactly what I told you.

Comment: @JonLin Now that I am at home: Sorry, you are right; I forgot to clear the query string too. The solution has more problems, because the path that is used actually exists on the server. I'll rewrite my answer, but your answer seems to work a lot better than mine.